# Understanding the nature and the impact of gain flatness on EVM of a transmit signal

Tags: rf, wireless, dsp

I have a signal which has a quite a steep slope in frequency domain (or gain non-flatness), in fact 3 dB.
This signal will go through an amplifier and it is going to be operated in the saturation region, so nonlinearity is going to play a big role.
My questions are the following:

1. How does gain flatness in frequency domain look like in time domain?
2. How does it affect the EVM of a signal (is it the impact of Inter-symbol interference?)
3. Will it have any impact on the linearity of the amplifier or are these two impairments completely mutually exclusive (if I may use this expression)?

Comment: "3 dB" isn't a meaningful description of a spectral slope.

Comment: ISI and EVM are different things. Orthogonal impairments will tend to add as power into EVM. Frequency slope and amplifier saturation will be partially correlated, so will add as more or less than power.

Comment: O.K. so I meant the impact of ISI on EVM

Comment: Why would frequency slope be correlated with amplifier linearity or saturation? Is there an explanation for this?